# D3js server side mouseover event not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, d3.js

I'm trying to render d3js from the server side using node.js and expressjs.

Been trying to register mouseover events for hours now but just can't seem to get it to work. My svg is rendering and i can change the attributes but *mouseover* and *mouseout* are just not being detected. Plus all the examples I can find seem to be of earlier versions of D3 and most of the API have changed. Feels like i'm getting something very basic wrong. but can't figure out what it is.

Desperately need help.

Am quite new at D3js so please let me know if i've missed out on providing some details.

A big thank you in advance.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var d3 = require('d3');
var JSDOM = require('jsdom').JSDOM;
var express = require('express');
var app = express()

var chartWidth = 500,
    chartHeight = 500;

var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(chartWidth / 2 - 10)
    .innerRadius(100);

var colours = ['#F00', '#000', '#000', '#000', '#000', '#000', '#000', '#000', '#000'];

function moveAndZoom() {
    var t = d3.event.translate;
    var s = d3.event.scale;

    var x = Math.min(
        (width / height) * (s - 1),
        Math.max(width * (1 - s), t[0]));

    var h = height / 4;
    var y = Math.min(
        h * (s - 1) + h * s,
        Math.max(height * (1 - s) - h * s, t[1]));

    mainGroup.style("stroke-width", ((1 / s) * 2) + "px");
    mainGroup.attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')scale(' + s + ')');
}

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 5])
    .on("zoom", moveAndZoom);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var pieData = [12, 31];
    const window = (new JSDOM('<html><head></head><body></body></html>', {
        pretendToBeVisual: true
    })).window;

    window.d3 = d3.select(window.document); //get d3 into the dom

    // do yr normal d3 stuff
    var svg = window.d3.select('body')
        .append('div').attr('class', 'container') //make a container div to ease the saving process
        .append('svg')
        .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
        .attr('width', chartWidth)
        .attr('height', chartHeight)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + chartWidth / 2 + ',' + chartWidth / 2 + ')')
        .style('pointer-events', "all");

    // var svg = d3.select('body').attr('height', chartHeight).attr('width', chartWidth);

    svg.selectAll('arc')
        .data(d3.pie()(pieData))
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        // .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'arc')
        .attr('d', arc)
        // .call(zoom)
        .attr('fill', function (d, i) {
            return colours[i];
            // console.log(d);
        })
        .attr('stroke', '#fff')
        .attr('stroke-width', "20px")
        .attr('stroke-opacity', 0.0)
        .on('click', function (d, i) {
            console.log("click", d);
        })
        .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
            console.log("mouseover", d);
            d3.select(this).transition().duration(100).attr("stroke-opacity", 1.0);
        })
        .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
            console.log("mouseout", d);
            d3.select(this).transition().duration(100).attr("stroke-opacity", 0.0);
        })

    res.send(window.d3.select('.container').html());
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: if you render the svg on the server and send some html to the client how do you think that the mouse event handlers get to the client? Attach the handler on the client side.

Comment: @rioV8 hey thanks, that makes sense. Maybe a really stupid question, but how would I do that? could you please point me in the right direction, maybe some example of attaching handlers on the client side. will pick up from there.

Comment: the same as do it on your server code, only in the browser

Comment: @rioV8 oh.. okay. I wanted to render everything server side.. So basically i'll have to render the svg as well as add the mouse event handlers on the client side then?

Comment: you can add the mouse events on the browser side by searching for the element and attach the handler. you can render the svg on the server. it all depends what you want to do in the handler

Comment: Ah! understood. Thanks.